# c# compare string to a number

Tags: c#

I want to compare if `(x > "355.0")`.

> But it says the error operator ">" cannot be applied to operands of
>   type '**string**' to '**string**'.

How do I go around fixing this issue ?

Comment: do you mean  if (x > "355.0").

Comment: yes haha. I just edited it. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Be careful to verify that the current culture allows that kind of floating point symbol (dot). Otherwise, you'll get "strange" results. See the [`float.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyzs0sca(v=vs.110).aspx) overloads that lets you define a cultural-specific (or general) comparison.

Comment: This is not an issue. CLR just don't know how to compare this: "foo" > "bar"? Why are trying to compare with string?

Comment: Please tell us what the result of the comparison should be if `x="4"`.

Answer (score 0):

Compare numbers instead:

```
if (double.Parse(x) > 355.0) ....
```

<strike>Or implement the > operator on strings.</strike>

Comment: You can't implement the `>` operator on strings.

Comment: Right. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string to double or float:

```
double.Parse("355.0")
```

or:

```
float.Parse("355.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Both x and the comparing object have to be a number of some sort. Currently `"355.0"` is a string. You'd have to parse it first.

```
(x > double.Parse("355.0"))
```

Should fix it. As long as x is a number of some sort.
If not, you'll have to do something like this.

```
int parsedX = parse.Float(x);
int parsedString = parse.Float("355.0");
if(parsedX > parsedString)
```

Comment: But x is a string, it was clear from the error message.
Why would you parse a string at runtime that is apparently a number at compile time?